# Issuu-Not working in Safari

Tags: issuu

I have a website that embeds issuu documents. Now it seems as the expanding and browsing through the document works in Firefox but not in Safari. You can try it out here: http://uniteich.at/service/agent  Nothing happens in Safari if I click on the document.
Here is the html-code snippet where I bind in the issuu-code:

```
<div class="issuu"> 
  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" style="width:320px;height:240px" id="add9c3c4-afc6-970e-36fb-28ae7e20a616" >
  <param name="movie" value="http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v2/IssuuReader.swf?mode=mini&amp;embedBackground=%23ffffff&amp;backgroundColor=%23222222&amp;documentId=120229092309-6b8da62cea0f428f95a491abc5302843" />
  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/>
  <param name="menu" value="false"/>
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/><embed src="http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v2/IssuuReader.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" menu="false" wmode="transparent" style="width:320px;height:240px" flashvars="mode=mini&amp;embedBackground=%23ffffff&amp;backgroundColor=%23222222&shareMenuEnabled=false&amp;documentId=<?php print($fields['field_issuu_id_value']->content);?>" /></object>
</div>
```

I would be very thankful for help,

thanks enne

Comment: I am having the same issue (no pun intended). Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: No, sry, not sure why's not working.

Comment: For me, I discovered it was because Safari did not have a flash plugin installed, and the Issuu embed code did not include a fallback for non-flash browsers. I just adjusted the code to display a message if Flash wasn't installed, and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This is Safari's responsibility for not rendering Flash content.

The embed code you're using is Issuu's old embed code that only includes the Flash embeds. If you use their new embed like this

```
<div data-configid="6943700/11183544" style="width:525px; height:376px;" class="issuuembed"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//e.issuu.com/embed.js" async="true"></script>
```

the embed will also render in browsers that don't support Flash (e.g. on the iPad etc).

You can get the new embed code from your document's page http://issuu.com/uniteich.at/docs/agent_3_final_web_0#embed or from the [Publisher Tools](http://issuu.com/home/publications) (open menu -> "Embed").